# Loop vertical li elements move left to right inside div with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite

I'm trying to make an animation, but I have hard time doing so. The idea is, to move all content of each li from left to right in infite loop.

```
$(function() {
 var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(true);
 var old_left = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left'));
 var top_indent = old_left - item_width;
 var right_indent = item_width;

 var animateBox = function() {
     $('#slides ul').animate({
        'top':top_indent,
         'left':right_indent/2

     },3700, function(){
        $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));
        $('#slides ul').css({'top':0});
        setTimeout(function() {animateBox(); }, 100);
     });
}
animateBox();
});
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

This is jsfiddle exampe : http://jsfiddle.net/euroc5y9/1/

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish.
What should the animation do/look like?

Answer (score 0):

Just check for left position inside *animateBox-function*:

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/euroc5y9/5/)

```
$(function() {
    var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(true);
    var old_left = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left'));
    var top_indent = old_left - item_width;
    var right_indent = item_width;
    var left = 0;

    var animateBox = function() {
        left = (left)? 0: (right_indent/2);

        $('#slides ul').animate({
            'top':top_indent,
            'left':left

        },1500, function(){
            $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));
            $('#slides ul').css({'top':0});
            setTimeout(function() {animateBox(); }, 100);
        });
    }
    animateBox();
});
```

Hope it helps.